# ssh tunnel cron job not running on system boot

Tags: server, bash, ssh, cron

### Goal

I have a ubuntu box which i use to tunnel to another Server, I would like to make sure that any time my system reboot it automatically creates the tunnel. So I been trying the following

### Created a Shell Script with embedded password to enable Tunnel

```
root@ubuntu1704:~# cat /root/sshtunnel.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -f -N root@192.168.48.105 -L 0.0.0.0:8443:192.168.68.14:443
expect "password:"
send "kn&Z6*\r"
expect eof
```

### What Works

If i run this manually then it works fine and my tunnel opens without any issues

### What Doesn't Work

I added this to
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.DJGY3i/crontab installed on Fri Jun 16 23:28:22 2017)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)

@reboot /root/sshtunnel.sh
```

But it's not really working

### What i have tried

1. I have tried using my putting cron in my user as well as root both doesn't work, Right now i have the in both. I think i have seen it randomly work but can't confirm
2. I enabled login on cron but not cron logs are empty /var/log/cron.log

Comment: Add "exit" on a single line, at the end of your script

Comment: @jones0610 thanks will try it, I just disabled the cron on root and left on my user profile only and reboot it worked this time without adding the exit, going to reboot it few times to see what's going on

Comment: You bet.  Your script should not require root privileges.  Cron failures should be e-mailed to the user who owns the crontab.  Type mailx to see if the job sent you anything.

Comment: @jones0610 without exit script as it i rebooted 3 times it worked first 2 and then didn't do anything on 3rd time, now added exit  and going to reboot few times

Comment: @jones0610 even with exit it's not consistent, one time it works and then another time it doesn't, Wish there was a way i can check if the tunnel is down and start it, but i am not sure how i can achieve that

Comment: You could do a traceroute and see which way the packets go.  Also, you might need to add a "&" to the end of the line in cron to make it run in the background.  And maybe >> /tmp/tunnel.log as a place to send messages to.  Generally speaking, programming errors will fail predictably, the same way each time.  Have you thought about calling the script in /etc/local or somewhere in the startup sequence?  Or in a script that you launch every time you boot up your machine?  Since the script should only run once I don't know that cron is the place to put it.

Comment: Are you sure the network is ready when the script starts?

Comment: rc.local worked few times and then it doest i added sleep 120 to my script to make it wait for everything else to finish before start tunnel still not working